# Process port-protocol form PID

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, netstat

If I have process ID and I want to know the port and Protocol of this process 
is there any command in `netstat` or other help me?

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -aon` will give you a list of open ports and what process (PID) has them open. You could then pipe the result to the `find` command to only list ports open with a specific PID.

For Example:

I want to see what ports process 820 has open

netstat -aon | find "820"

This will provide some false positives if there is a port number or process name that also contains the number 820.